# Accessing plugin settings in template

Tags: plugins

How can I access plugin settings in the template?

I have `config.php` file defined in plugin directory and i want to access these values (or their overwritten values) in Twig templates.

I tried `{{craft.pluginHandle.getSettings}}` but it didn't work, it throws an error that such a method does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
craft.app.getPlugins().getPlugin('pluginHandle').getSettings()
```